# Did Solara ever learn Eli's secret?

Tags: movie, the-book-of-eli

At the end of *The Book of Eli*, we the audience learn that

> Eli is blind and has been the whole movie.  We learn the secret when Carnegie first opens Eli's book and sees that it is written in Braille.  But Solara was with Eli on Alcatraz at that point, so she never saw the Braille and may well not have known what it meant in any event.  I saw no sign of that Solara ever learned of Eli's blindness but I may have missed something.

Did Solara ever learn Eli's secret?

> EDIT: My assumption is that Eli recited the book and then died within a week, presumably of complications from his gunshot wound.  2 words per second for 16 hours a day gets the job done in one week, assuming an upper bound of 800,000 words in the King James Bible.  So I don't think Eli and Solara spent enough time together on Alcatraz for his little mistakes to give him away.

Comment: @KyleJones I don't think the end period could have been so short. Even if Eli could have managed to average speaking 2 words a second for 16 hours a day, which is questionable, it is unlikely that Lombardi could have maintained writing at that pace.

Comment: @Xantec Eli was a divine being.  Lombardi had staff to spell him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Book-of-Eli,-The.html), yes she found out at the end (he removed his goggles, though there are several scenes in the movie where he doesn't wear his goggles eg: in the house with the husband/wife cannibals).
I don't recall that scene in the film, though that could be either a) my memory, b) a deleted/missing scene.

Comment: Very interesting reading, that script, seeing the difference between it and the finished film.